# How to check if a client can use windows authentication

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

My ORACLE (10g) sqlnet.ora has `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(NTS)`. I need to validate that no client is using Windows authentication to connect. What can I check next to make sure they don't ?

Comment: A user would have to be specifically created to be authenticated by Windows. It won't happen automatically. If you create a user authenticated by a password, they will have to use the password. That parameter exists more to allow Oracle server processes to connect or server-side scripts to connect transparently.

Comment: OK, what SELECT should I run to see that it needs Windows autentication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check AUTHENTICATION_TYPE in the DBA_USERS view. Users who are authenticated externally (EXTERNAL in the view), are authenticated by the operating system. A user cannot be both internally and externally authenticated, or be altered to switch authentication methods once created. If you haven't deliberately created externally authenticated users, then you won't have a problem.

See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ntqrf/overview-of-manually-administering-external-users-and-roles.html#GUID-8A209E30-4BA9-4993-80F5-AF0A82ADEB5B